# WiX light.exe throws the Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow exception

Tags: .net, wix

I'm getting the following exception trying to build the msi file for a .NET application.

```
----------+++ Linking d:\analytics\trunk\bin64\snapshot.msi
light.exe : error LGHT0001 : Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Exception Type: System.OverflowException

Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Msi.SummaryInformation.SetProperty(Int32 index,     Object property)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Binder.UpdateSummaryInfo(Database db)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Binder.GenerateDatabase(Output output)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Binder.Bind(Output output)
   at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Tools.Light.Run(String[] args)
Command returned non zero code - 1.
```

Does anybody know what may be the problem?

Comment: The problem is reproduced "sometimes". Several minutes later the same project got built without any changes made to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the wix binaries wix.dll. The strange part is that some time it is working and some times it fails. In order to solve the problem this assembly needs to be build after manipulating the code. Below are steps that I followed to resolve the problem:

1. Download the code from 'http://sourceforge.net/' site.
2. Build the code in VS 2010 environment.
3. Correct the `SummaryInformation.SetProperty` code by doing the following things.
   a. First collect the upper and lower byte in the long variables rather than directly casting to int.
   b. Add the exceptional handing in this method.
4. Add the assembly version 2.0.5805.0.
5. Add the assembly file version 2.0.5805.0.
6. Build the wix.dll assembly using the VS 2010.
7. Change the public key and public key token as it is present in download binary wix.dll file.
8. Copy the new build wix.dll in our project and it starts working.

Regards
Navanit Katiyar
GlobalLogic pvt Ltd.